# Removing copyright tag from the footer

Tags: php, wordpress

When I remove

```
<div id="footer">
    <?php echo date("Y"); echo " "; bloginfo('name'); ?>
</div>
```

from the footer on [this page](http://e.felipes.se) the webpage starts to display things weird. The background color for example disappears. Why is that?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but shouldn't you be leaving the copyright information alone?

Comment: Try leaving the <div> and </div> and just remove the middle line ie       <?php echo date("Y"); echo " "; bloginfo('name'); ?>  it may be that div is required for the structure of the page but cannot say for sure without seeing more code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `#main` is CSS to `overflow:hidden` or `overflow: auto;`.

This is because `.post` has `float: left;`. Everything that floats isn't in the flow of the document anymore. Hence the `#main` doesn't know the height of the elements in it.